# google apps db.model ignores StringPropertys which i defined

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, model

I'm making a BBS by using google apps. It works, but it's under 5000 words by each thread. I unioned 10 `db.StringProperty()` of `db.model`.
I planned to union 1000 `StringProperty()`, but it doesn't work for more than 10.
Google apps engine ignores additional `StringProperty()`'s.

The error said:

> 'TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found'.

The code is like this:
model.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
import uuid
import re
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Post(db.Model):
    user    = db.UserProperty()
    ct      = db.IntegerProperty()
    uid     = db.StringProperty()
    indx    = db.StringProperty()
    title   = db.StringProperty()
    updated_at  = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    entry = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry1 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry2 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry3 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry4 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry5 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry6 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry7 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry8 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry9 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry10 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry11 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    entry12 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    ...
    entry999 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
```

I'm just testing it at localhost:8080.
Google apps ignores from entry10. entry9 is recognized.
I read google site guide, but I didn't find any que about it.
If defining entry1-1000 is impossible, I want to define as many as it allows.
Or it doesn't allow any more element?
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: It should be possible, but it looks like a bad design. What are they all for? Do you know there is a [db.StringListProperty()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#StringListProperty)

Comment: ps: Google Apps != Google App Engine

Comment: What the? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: i read guide lines which said that the database allow us to insert only 1000 datas.i believed that at the first place.so i designed the BBS site to deel with the db.model class with 1000 StringProperty.

Comment: i m making a BBS kind of 2ch or 4channel without pics. i will try StringListProperty(). thanks.

Comment: "i read guide lines which said that the database allow us to insert only 1000 datas"... umm, where? The datastore can store as many entities as you can throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because you are trying to do:

```
u'a' + u'b' + None
```

Somewhere... probably one of your entity fields is `None`

Comment: thanks! u r absolutely right.i believed that it does add None.i thought i saw added output like 'Nice to meet you. None None None NoneNone',but it was just placed side by side on the HTML(Django).